# Can you order an elastic search query result? Force it to the end if it has True in a field

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm running an ES query

```
data = es.search(index='indexName', size=10000,body={"query": {"exists": {"field": "field_name"}}})
```

But I want the the results to reorder if it has another field called `'reviewed'` set as `True`.

If it is True it should get moved to the end. The query is getting fed into a table.

```
item    reviewed
-----------------
apple     [x]   <----check boxes
pear      [ ]
banana    [ ]

[ submit ]
```

then on reload

```
item    reviewed
-----------------
pear      [ ]
banana    [ ]
apple     [ ]

[ submit ]
```

Comment: why do you want elastic search to sort based on the reviewed value as True. You can write a custom function and check the condition and then sort it accordingly.

Comment: @min2bro We have documents that get reviewed, if someone has reviewed it it gets set as True, and I'd like already viewed documents to get pushed back in the order so new documents rise to the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is simply boost the documents that have `reviewed` set to false using a bool/should clause, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "field_name"
        }
      },
      "should": {
        "term": {
          "reviewed": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is going to happen is that all documents having a field called `field_name` will be matched, but all the ones having `reviewed` set to false will be boosted higher than those with `reviewed` set to true.

Comment: This query achieves that behavior. Can you try and let me know?

Comment: It seems to do the opposite. It sends all reviewed: True, to the top of the table, setting it to False has no positive effect either. Thanks for help though, this seems to be the right process, maybe my code is wonky

Comment: On my tests, all false are at the top and true at the bottom. Maybe provide a gist so I can reproduce the issue on my end?

Comment: So the data is sent to the DOM and I'm using Jinja to build a table from the data, so it might be possible Jinja is reorganizing the data?

Comment: I have no idea about that, all I'm saying is that as far as ES is concerned, the data is returned the way you expect.

Comment: Yes it works! It was my data that wasn't correct. I'm now actually trying to combine another query in with it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55962875/how-do-i-combine-these-two-queries-in-elastic-search-python