# How do I combine these two queries in elastic search python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have two queries I would like to combine

First one returns results that have the "analysis.data_counts" value greater than 0.

```
{
   "query": {
       "range" : {
           "analysis.data_counts" : {
               "gte" : 1,
           }
       }
   }
}
```

The second one sees if it has a certain field and also checks another fields bool value and if it has that value boosts it higher in the query so they appear first

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "data_types"
        }
      },
      "should": {
        "term": {
          "reviewed": False
        },

      }
    }
  }
})
```

So I need to tie them together so I can get results that have "analysis.data_counts" >= 1, have the field type "data_types" and make the "reviewed" == False appear before the True ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "data_types"
          }
        },
        {
          "range" : {
            "analysis.data_counts" : {
               "gte" : 1,
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": {
        "term": {
          "reviewed": False
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```